# AngularJS with MongoDB, data is pulled from database, but cannot display with ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, html, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to get data from the DB and display it using `ng-repeat`. The `getAll` function from the factory does the job properly, I get an object with all the data, but it is not displayed properly. In the table I only get the first index, with nothing after it.

If i try with `for(i = 0 ; i < DataService.persons.length ; i++)`, it works fine, but I cannot use it with ng-repeat.

```js
var testReactie = angular.module('testReactie', ['ngRoute']);

testReactie.config(function($routeProvider) {
   $routeProvider

       .when('/', {
        templateUrl : 'instructiuni.ejs'

       })
       .when('/form', {
        templateUrl : 'form.ejs',
        controller : 'formContr'
       })
       .when('/test', {
        templateUrl : 'joc.ejs',
        controller : 'gameContr'
       })
       .when('/stat', {
        templateUrl : 'scoruri.ejs',
        controller : 'statContr',
        resolve: {
            postPromise:['DataService', function(DataService){
                return DataService.getAll();
            }]
        }
       });
    
});


testReactie.factory('DataService', ['$http', function($http) {
    var o = {
        persons:[],
        person:{}
    };
    
    o.getAll = function(){
        
      return $http.get('/db').success(function(data){
        o.persons = data;
        
      });  
    };

    o.create = function() {
      return $http.post('/db', o.person).success(function(data){
        o.persons.push(data);
      });
    };
    
    return o;
}]);

testReactie.controller('mainContr',function($scope) {
    
});

testReactie.controller('statContr',function($scope, DataService) {

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <h2>Scoruri</h2>

    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Nr.</th>
                <th>Sex</th>
                <th>Varsta</th>
                <th>Timp Mediu</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            
            <div ng-repeat = "pers in DataService.persons">
                <tr>
                    <td>{{$index + 1}}</td>
                    <td>{{pers.sex}}</td>
                    <td>{{pers.varsta}}</td>
                    <td>{{pers.timp}}</td>
                </tr>
            </div>
            
        </tbody>
    </table>
    
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot run a factory as a controller

In your controller do something like

```
testReactie.controller('mainContr', ['DataService', '$scope', function(DataService, $scope) {
    DataService.getAll().then(function(successData){ // a promise helps you do something when it's resolved
        $scope.awesomeData = successData;
    }
});
```

Change your factory's get all to be something like

```
o.getAll = function(){
    var promise = $q.defer(); // the $q helps create a promise

      return $http.get('/db').success(function(data){
            promise.resolve(data); // promise returns data when resolved
      });  
return promise; // returns a promise
};
```

your template should be

```
<div ng-repeat = "pers in awesomeData">
```

This is because when you have it in your template, it will automatically call $scope.awesomeData. So when you had DataService then it was calling $scope.DataService which was undefined.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem. It was from the HTML. I added the ng-repeat directive in a div and it broke the table. After deleting the div and adding the directive in the  tag, it worked fine.